# one2many field on Transient Model lines disappear in the wizard view when exception occurred

Tags: odoo-13

I have a model this with model:

```py
class WizardAccountInvoiceAssignAdvance(models.TransientModel):
    advance_ids = fields.One2many(
        comodel_name='wizard.account.invoice.assign.advance.payment',
        inverse_name='wizard_id',
        string='Allocated Advances',
        required=True, )
    
class WizardAccountInvoiceAssignAdvancePayment(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'wizard.account.invoice.assign.advance.payment'

    wizard_id = fields.Many2one('wizard.account.invoice.assign.advance', string='Assign Advance Form')
    payment_id = fields.Integer(string="Payment ID")
    advance_id = fields.Many2one('account.move', string="Advance Payment")
    amount = fields.Float("Payment Amount", required=False)
```

with default_get(self, fields) It will set the lines on advance_ids. On the wizard view the user select the lines and create an entry move when action_button is clicked. Everything is fine, but  the function has an control when the amount is zero or negative.

```xml
<footer>
    <button name="action_button"
            string="Apply Advances"
            type="object"
            class="btn-primary"/>
    <button string="Cancel" class="btn-default" special="cancel"/>
</footer>
```

If raise happens the lines on advances ids will go away on the wizard wiew.

```py
def action_button(self):
    for rec in self:
        if not rec.advance_ids.filtered(lambda line: line.amount < 0.0):
            raise UserError(_("Amount cant be 0.0 or negative value"))
```

How can Fix this !!
Thks !

Answer (score 1):

use attribute **force_save** for the fields which are disappearing.

```
force_save="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the view, when a field of the lines has the readonly="1" activated, the lines disappear, when an exception occurs.
[image: field student_id with readonly="1"]

[image]

If you remove the field readonly="1", the lines do appear
[image]

If you need the attribute readonly="1", in some field of the lines, then you have to compulsorily put the field force_save="1"